# IntelliJ: importing play.api._ breaks other imports

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, import, playframework

Starting on two new things at the same time: IntelliJ + Scala (+ Play).

I am having some strange issue on IntelliJ reporting errors on the editor if I import play.api._ on the same class. Project is a new project created with IntelliJ scala+play 2.4 template.

Example file ImportError.scala in app/controllers/subpackage:

```
package controllers.subpackage

import play.api._
import controllers.ClassToImport

class ImportError {
  val instance = new ClassToImport()
}
```

IntelliJ editor is givin me error on line "import controllers.ClassToImport":
"Cannot resolve symbol ClassToImport"

If I select 'Recompile ImportError.scala", the console gives no compile errors.

If I change the class by removing the play.api import like this:

```
package controllers.subpackage

import controllers.ClassToImport

class ImportError {
  val instance = new ClassToImport()
}
```

Then IntelliJ no longer gives me errors on the editor.

Also here are other observations of the situation:

- If I cut-paste the latter import before the play import, IntelliJ will change my imports to: 'import controllers.ClassToImport' and 'import play.api.{controllers, _}', so here must be some clue. Why does it think I want controllers from play api?
- If I change the order of the two imports then both editor and compile result are happy.
- If I change the play import to "import play.api.controllers" then editor is happy but compile result is "object controllers is not a member of package play.api". I do not understand this at all, as to my understanding (as shown by the error) there does not exist play.api.controllers, so why is IntelliJ editor accepting it?

The above example is a isolated example of the problem I am facing in a real project with importing play.api._ with IntelliJ. Should be easily reproducable with the latest IntelliJ IDEA community 2016.2.4.

Comment: A piece of new information: If I go to the External Libraries of my project and select the "com.typesafe.play:play_2.11:2.4.8.jar" and "Open libary settings" and remove the sources, then issue is resolved. No errors on editor or when doing compile.

Answer (score 0):

The prblem here is that you are importing everything from `play.api`, and inside that there is a package named `controllers`.

So, when in the next statement, you try to import `controllers.ClassToImport`, it is searching class `ClassToImport` in `play.api.controllers`, which will fail.

To fix that, you may try to reorder your imports

```
import controllers.ClassToImport
import play.api._
```

or rename the play `controllers` package:

```
import play.api.{controllers => playControllers, _}
import controllers.ClassToImport
```